# Stored procedure returns 0 when bit is default to NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server outputs a 0 when it is supposed to output null. And this does not happen in every SQL Server. I checked the version of SQL and they are both 2014.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE wt.testbit 
     (@is_bit bit = NULL)
AS
    SELECT @is_bit
GO


EXEC wt.testbit
```

This returns a result set with 1 row and 1 column, that 1 column is null in some environments and 0 in others

Comment: No it doesn't, it returns `NULL`. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd32cd0dc4d7d99e6147d6017ccd1523)

Comment: @larnu . Yea I said some environments.

Comment: Can you provide a replication?

Comment: On every version of SQL Server, this procedure will return its input in a single-row, single-column result set of type `BIT`, and its return value will be an `INT` that is 0. If there's a difference in "environments", you're most likely looking at a difference in client code (for example, how SSMS presents the results, whether you've checked the "results to text" option, etc.)

Comment: Edited the question to address confusion between "return" vs "select"

Comment: If you are observing the procedure returning `0` as a `BIT` in the result set even when called with no parameters, you've found a bug in *something*, but almost certainly not SQL Server. Check your other assumptions: that the sproc is what you think it is, that the command you execute it is what you think it is and that the client tool used to execute this command is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing result sets with return codes. A stored procedure can emit none , one or many result sets. However it can have only one return code/result code. The return code by default is 0 (if you try to return null it will either fail or coerce it to 0 , depending on versions/db/etc)